# concurrency via message queues: how to avoid recursion?

Tags: concurrency, message-queue, pseudocode

I am working on a concurrency system based on message queues with an underlying thread pool. A queue can target other queues. Also a queue can be targeted by multiple queues (i.e. children) to create a tree hierarchy and to prioritise some of the queues.

I want to avoid signalling threads each time a message is queued while the queue (and its children) is (are) already being drained.

So the queue knows if it's `sleeping` or `running`. Transition from `sleeping` to `running` is easy. That can be done when a new message is queued.

I am more concerned about the other way around. How can I avoid missing messages/events when I transition from `running` to `sleeping`? To clarify: this is not an atomic step. The queue also can't go to sleep when its children still need attention.

At the moment in the sleep function I set the state to `sleeping`, then check if the current queue or its children have any pending events that were missed. If so, I wake the queue back up. But doesn't that potentially cause an infinite recursion of awake - sleep - awake - sleep - ... ?

How can I avoid this, or what's the proper way to setup such a queue system?

In pseudo code:

```
atomic state = sleeping
target = anotherQueue
children = queues that target this queue

func Async(event)
{
   get lock
   push event onto queue (i.e. array/fifo/...)
   release lock
   this.wakeup()
}


func wakeup()
{
    If (state == running) { return }
    state = running     
    !target ? drain() : target.wakeup()
}


func drain()
{
     while (event = next() )
     {
        event.run()
     }
     sleep()
}


func sleep()
{
  state = sleeping

  *** what if an event is posted during the transition from running to sleeping? ***

  //check if events have been missed
  If (event.count > 0)  
  {
    this.wakeup()
  }

  //check children: don't sleep if they have pending events
  If (children.haveEvents) { this.wakeup }

}


func next()
{
   get lock
   nextEvent = pop event from queue
   release lock

   If (!nextEvent)
   {
      //check each child queue for an event
      children.nextEvent
   }
   return nextEvent
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. If you don't use recursion in your sleep and wakeup functions then you won't have this problem.

Comment: Ok. How can the recursion be replaced in such a way I don't miss events while transitioning from running to sleeping?

Comment: Well I'd write the main loop as `while(true) {drain();}` and then `sleep` doesn't need to call `wakeup`, it can just return without sleeping. To avoid the potential deadlock I'd use a condition variable for `state`.

Comment: @immibis Good, might want to make it a real answer.